# Understanding "t'en veut beaucoup d'avoir été choisi à sa place"

Tags: grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques

I encountered this while reading *Astérix.* The line of dialogue, uttered by Cleopatra to an architect building her a palace, is as follows:

> Je te préviens, Numérobis, Amonbofis, ton concurrent, t'en veut beaucoup d'avoir été choisi à sa place pour construire le palais de César.

I understand this to mean "I should warn you that your competitor Numérobis wants very much to have been chosen instead of you to construct Caesar's palace."

However, the *t'en* is odd to me. Why not omit that and say *à ta place* instead? Is this really the best way to phrase that? I would never have known to write it that way.

Comment: *En vouloir à quelqu'un* [se trouve](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/en%20vouloir%20%c3%a0%20qn) dans tous les dictionnaires. *À la/ta/sa/ place* [aussi](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/%C3%A0%20la%20place%20de).

Comment: Colloquially, I often use the construction: "je t'en voudrai(s) pas si tu ...".

Comment: @Laure you have to appreciate that it's not a simple matter to distinguish between cases where *se/te/me/etc* or *en/y* are present on their own merits from cases where they're forming an unfamiliar set phrase like *en vouloir à quelqu'un.* For instance, if in some context I saw the words *t'en donne*, my first thought would not be that it's a set phrase *en donner à quelqu'un* with an idiomatic meaning, but rather the more obvious interpretation that something is being given to someone. Same here. It did not occur to me to look this up as a set phrase.

Comment: The citation is wrong, leading DRz into thinking Frank is wrong. He's only wrong of knowing Astérix too much. «Je te préviens, Numérobis, Amonbofis, ton concurrent, t’en veut beaucoup d’avoir été choisi à sa place...» Amonbofis is resentful at Numérobis, and Cléopâtre is warning Numérobis about it.

Comment: Oh, right you are. That's my mistake. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit different. It means that “Amonbofis (your competitor)  is *resentful* toward you”. *En vouloir à quelqu'un* means to be resentful.

Answer (score 1):

"Il t'en veut" = "il te en veut" = "il en veut **à** toi", he is mad **at** you

"t'en" = "te en" = "**en**vers **t**oi" = towards/**at** **you**

But we cannot say "te en", which is why we replace it by "t'en".

Another example is "je t'en prie" for "if it pleases you" ("you're welcome").

In both case it is a sentiment (negative or positive) express *towards* you, *at* you.

> Je te préviens, Numérobis, ton concurrent, **t'en** veut beaucoup d'avoir été choisi à sa place pour construire le palais de César.

*becomes*

> I warn you, Edifis, your competitor, is really mad **at you** for having been chosen in his place to build the palace of Caesar.